# Understanding SurfaceHolder concept

Tags: android, surfaceholder

I want to write a program that a ball move on screen, because of this, i read many tutorial and i cant understand this line:

```
mHolder = getHolder();
mHolder.addCallback(this);
```

what is "`this`" parameter in `addCallback` method? why i use this method?
i read about `SurfaceView` and `SurfaceHolder` and `Canvas` but i cant good understand `SurfaceHolder`.what does it do?

I know maybe my question was stupid but this is a question ! Please explain about this concept.

Answer (score 5):

"this" is a basic Java/OO concept ... here it refers to the object calling mHolder.addCallback(). In your class declaration you will see at the top that it "implements SurfaceHolder.Callback".

Since your class implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, it *IS* an instance of SurfaceHolder.Callback, and it can therefore pass a reference to itself ('this') to functions that take a SurfaceHolder.Callback parameter.

As for the "concept" of SurfaceHolder, it's merely the interface for app code to interact with a Surface. It's used in [SurfaceView.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/view/SurfaceView.java?av=f) ... look for the private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder declaration.

This is 100% speculation but I imagine SurfaceHolder was separated out this way because the designers envisaged having other kinds of SurfaceViews and wanted a standard way for app code to interact with them.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i cant understand getHoder() method. What does it do this method?

Comment: SurfaceView.getHolder() returns the SurfaceHolder interface you use to interact with the Surface. I don't know how else or how better it can be explained than that. Maybe a close look at SurfaceView.java and SurfaceHolder.java will make it clearer.